# Why does overloading operator < for sort on an array of dynamically created object doesn't work?

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting, struct, operator-overloading

I was playing around with c++ and noticed a very strange thing happening:

- I created a custom struct which had a value and index.
- I implemented an overloading operator '<' in the custom struct.
- I created a vector with the custom struct I created.
- I did a sort() on the vector that I created.

Here is the strange thing. When I created the vector of custom class statically, it would sort just fine. However, when I create the vector of dynamically created struct, it does not sort well. (Pardon my terrible english btw). I think it would be easier if I just show the code.

Here is my code:

CustomStruct structure:

```
struct CustomStruct{

    int value;
    int index;

    bool operator<(const CustomStruct &rhs){
        return value<rhs.value;
    }

    CustomStruct(int index, int value){
        this->index = index;
        this->value = value;
    }
};
```

I created 2 custom structs, added dummy values and sorted them as following:

```
vector<CustomStruct> firstStruct;
vector<CustomStruct*> secondStruct;

vector<int> arr = {5,1,4,2,3};

for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    firstStruct.push_back(CustomStruct(i, arr.at(i)));
    secondStruct.push_back(new CustomStruct(i, arr.at(i)));
}

sort(firstStruct.begin(), firstStruct.end());
sort(secondStruct.begin(), secondStruct.end());
```

and when I print them by doing:

```
cout << "First Struct: ";
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
    cout << firstStruct.at(i).value << " ";
}
cout << endl;

cout << "Second Struct: ";
for(int i=0; i<5; i++){ 
    cout << secondStruct.at(i)->value << " ";
}
cout << endl;
```

My out put is:

```
First Struct: 1 2 3 4 5
Second Struct: 1 5 4 2 3
```

So, why is it that when I create a vector with objects dynamically,

```
vector<CustomStruct*> secondStruct;
```

it does not sort them correctly?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `secondStruct` is a vector containing memory addresses. So it will just sort by memory address.